# phpMyAdmin unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, phpmyadmin

When I tried to install phpMyAdmin it gave me this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: dbconfig-mysql but it is not installable or
                       dbconfig-no-thanks but it is not installable or
                       dbconfig-common (< 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: php-tcpdf but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I use the installation command `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext` and I also tried `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Apt's "not installable" means that the package with that name does not exist.  Since these are standard Ubuntu packages in 16.04 and above, it indicates your repositories are not up to date or you have excluded some essential repositories in your Apt sources, or you are trying to install a version of phpmyadmin intended for 16.04 or later onto an older Ubuntu.

Comment: *"Apt's "not installable" means that the package with that name does not exist."* That is not correct; the package may exist but be uninstallable for other reasons such as unsatisfiable dependencies. The only way to find out why the package is uninstallable is to try to explicitly install it.